# How to include a separate git repository with tests in Heroku pipeline?

Tags: reactjs, github, heroku, mocha.js, heroku-ci

We are trying to set up a CI pipeline for our React application in Heroku.

For now, we have automatic deployment setup for our application which is triggered by any commit to the git repository. 
We need to run tests before heroku releases the new version, and Heroku should only release the new version if all tests pass. Our tests are in a separate Git Repository, and we are using Mocha, Chai and puppeteer for the tests.

How can this be achieved in Heroku?

We have tried to include the tests repository in Heroku, but Heroku does not allow to connect to the second git repo, because it is already connected to the React application's git repo. 
We went through Heroku docs but could not find anything that would solve our issue.

The final flow needed is: We commit to the application's git repo -> it triggers Heroku automatic CI -> Heroku runs tests that are in a separate git repository -> if tests pass, Heroku releases the new version.

Comment: "Our tests are in a separate Git Repository"—why? I've never seen a workflow where the tests live in a separate repository. How do you link revisions in your test repository with revisions in the main codebase?